# Grails 2.5.3 NPE on production deployment (assets-pipeline)

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I got the following stacktrace when I try to access login page of my application:

```
    21.03.2016 19:01:52,746: (HVK3) GrailsExceptionResolver: NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /wmp-hvk3-development/login/auth
Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: null
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Hashtable.hash(Hashtable.java:262)
        at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:459)
        at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:951)
        at asset.pipeline.grails.AssetProcessorService.getResolvedAssetPath(AssetProcessorService.groovy:57)
        at asset.pipeline.grails.AssetProcessorService.asset(AssetProcessorService.groovy:72)
        at asset.pipeline.grails.CachingLinkGenerator.asset(CachingLinkGenerator.groovy:32)
        at asset.pipeline.grails.CachingLinkGenerator.resource(CachingLinkGenerator.groovy:24)
        at gsp_wmpHvk3Development_loginauth_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(gsp_wmpHvk3Development_loginauth_gsp.groovy:67)
```

Application works perfectly in `test environment` on local workstation but this stacktrace occurs when I deploy to production.

Im not sure what to make out of it, I guess there is a problem with the assets-pipeline assets path since `AssetProcessorService.groovy:57` states:

[image]

I'm on RedHat linux running tomcat 7 with java 1.7 with assets pipeline 2.7.2 plugin as `compile` dependency and spring security core plugin 2.0.0 `compile` time dependency.

Comment: could it be a problem with upper/lower case in a filename?

Comment: could you be more spesifix which file are you referring to. This could make sense but then again it does not explain why it works in test but not after deployed

Comment: Could you show your loginauth_gsp, especially 67 line?

Comment: That is compiled binary so there is not much to show. The actual file is login/auth.gsp and line 67 has `</div>` in this case

Comment: regarding the filename - if you develop on a windows machine and run on a *nix machine, it could be that it does not find a certain asset on *nix because of a upper/lower case problem which is ignored by windows

Comment: regarding the `loginauth_gsp.groovy` - check the docs or google a bit: you can get the compiled .gsp file. And there you will find the reason for your NPE on line 67... There are several ways to get the `_gsp.groovy` file. One of them can be found here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2013/06/grails-goodness-compiling-gsp-from.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by missing configuration in BuildConfig. I added the following to the end of the file and it fixed this:

```
// This closure is passed the command line arguments used to start the war process.
    grails.war.copyToWebApp = { args ->
        fileset(dir: "web-app") {
            include(name: "js/**")
            include(name: "css/**")
            include(name: "WEB-INF/**")
        }
    }
```